# python plot a numpy array with matplotlib

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, neural-network

I am a relatively beginner in python and I am trying to learn the functioning of a one-neuron neuronal network. I got a code example in sololearn (an app to learn python & co). 
I am trying to explain and analyse the code line by line to make it available to everyone explaining it as much in detail as possible.
see here the code (comments being mine):
https://code.sololearn.com/cauWDig9GDUl

There is a first phase in which seeds are created:

```
def __init__(self):
    random.seed(1)
    self.weights = 2 * random.random((2, 1)) - 1
```

self.weights is a numpy array:

```
print('initial weights',self.weights)
print('type of weights', type(self.weights))
```

initial weights [[-0.16595599][ 0.44064899]]

type of weights is class 'numpy.ndarray'

further on the weights are adjusted in a train phase:

```
def train(self, inputs, outputs, num):
...
```

What I want to do is plot all the weights along the 10000 iteration learning process (the learning process is run 10000 times) and see the evolution of the weights graphically.
How can I do that?
Do I need to pass all the weights to two lists like this:?

```
weigths1=[w1,w2,w3,....,w10000]
weigths2=[x1,x2,x3,....,x10000]
```

where numpy array weight1= [[w1][x1]], weight2=[[w2][x2]] etc

How do I do that?
Can I create a list of numpy arrays?
Does it serve me anything?
The following does not work:

```
weightslist=[]
#repeat in every iteration:
weightslist.append(self.weights)
```

And more in general: having a series of numpy arrays of m x n dimension, how do I extract the series of values in position i,j of the array mxn in order to generate data for a plot with matplotlib (or whatever other library to plot).

thanks.

Comment: You can create a list of numpy arrays, but I'd recommend to only use numpy and create and array for the weights with `weights_array = np.zeros((10000, 2))` and assign the new weights in each step to `weights_array[iteration_number] = w_new, x_new`. If this is possible in your case, I'll post a more comprehensive answer.

Comment: I will try. I think it is possible, weights_array[iteration_number] = w_new, x_new is a simple super cool idea. How do I extract w_new from self.weights=[[w_new],[x_new]]. Sorry I am really new to numpy? I am looking for something like:  w_new=position 1,0 of selft.weights, and x_new=position 2,0 of self.weights

Comment: Extract it with indexing. `w_new = self.weights[0]` and `x_new = self.weights[1]`.

Comment: Does it work in your case?